# The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this, happening in main function in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, xaml

This error message jump out in a sudden without any change

I am using Application_Startup() as start up function to invoke MainWindow

```
 public partial class App : Application
{
    public string FileName;
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        //Thread nthrd = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MainWindowStartupMethod));
        //nthrd.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        //nthrd.Start();
        //nthrd.Join();
        MainWindow wnd = new MainWindow();
```

The error is happening in the last line "public MainWindow()"

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public WizardSetup data = new WizardSetup();
    public Connectiontest ConnectionObj;
    public delegate void ZoneFocusContentUpdateEventHandler(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e);
    WizardProcessBar Processor;
    Point InitialPosition = new Point();//using for image translate
    public bool WizardToHWSucceed = false;
    public MainWindow()
```

I do know the main() function should be STA and it is showing here by system default:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Application Entry Point.
    /// </summary>
    [System.STAThreadAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
    public static void Main() {
        TPACquisitionWizard.App app = new TPACquisitionWizard.App();
        app.InitializeComponent();
        app.Run();
    }
```

The project works with a new STA thread which is showing in comments in first code section, but it was working before to show MainWindow in main thread.Even I change "StartupUri = "MainWindow.xaml" in App.xaml does not work.
So my question is how to go back to previous method using main thread

Comment: The interesting is that it works with exe but not debug mode

Comment: Why oh why do novices _always_ do `nthrd.Start();  nthrd.Join();`???  Drives me batty

Comment: Why does your WPF app have a `Main()` anyway??? This isn't WinForms.  WPF has a completely different startup mechanism driven by **App.xaml**.   I hope you didn't create a console app and decided to plonk WPF into it because that will just make fairys lose their wings

Comment: _"The interesting is that it works with exe but not debug mode"_ - that's why it's called a _debugger_.  Just because something appears to run successfully, doesn't mean it's not doing something wonky behind the scenes

Comment: First, "public MainWindow()" looks like the signature for a constructor - that might be related to the error.  I'm not sure what its purpose is as shown.  What is the actual error message that you see?  Second, if you create a new WPF project and don't touch anything, you can click "Start" and it runs fine - MainWindow is wired up properly by default.  What are you trying to accomplish by changing the default code?

Comment: @ElementalPete That's the thing. There's alot of evidence there that he hasn't run the _New WPF Application wizard_.  There's no need for a `        MainWindow wnd = new MainWindow();` in the **App.xaml.cs**.  I'm assuming that's what it is.  My money is still a console app

Comment: @MickyD Not using nthrd.Start(); nthrd.Join() is because of not creating new threads, and I did New WPF Application Wizard long time ago for this project, ` MainWindow wnd = new MainWindow();` in the App.xaml.cs is just for start up

Comment: @ElementalPete "public MainWindos()" indeed is constructor and error is happening here and stop here. The error message is what it shows in title

Comment: @MickyD main() function is not showing in my code, it is in App.g.i.cs, I just check it has STA property

Comment: I doubt that sam, your program was either never WPF In the first place or you have modified your program to such an extent that the original WPF goodness has been lost

Comment: @MickyD I did not change something and Once I get back to check it in the other day, it happened. But I may lose something in System registering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, it sounds like the easiest way to get this working would be to create a new WPF application and then copy in any useful code that you want to keep.  You are writing code in dark, secret corners of your project where I suspect that code does not need to be written.

After you create your new project, immediately click "start" and make sure that it works.  As you copy over code, ensure that any changes you are making does not cause the program to quit running.

EDIT:  Here is my code from App.xaml in a working project

```
<Application x:Class="MyProject.App" 
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModel"
             StartupUri="ControlPanel.xaml" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">

</Application>
```

Note the StartupUri - when I click "Start", I see ControlPanel.xaml.  I have a resource dictionary in here (not shown), but not much custom code at all.  Here is my app.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Threading;

namespace MyProject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        static App()
        {
            DispatcherHelper.Initialize();
        }
    }
}
```

The one line of code was autogenerated, I think by MvvmLight toolkit.  I have not touched this file, and this is a production project...

Comment: That is one idea, but I will consider this as final step

Comment: @SamXia Throw away all that stuff you have right now, and start over with a new WPF project. Do not modify the application startup code.

Comment: If public MainWindow() is a constructor and that's where the error is thrown, then the error is due to how you are instantiating your window.  None of my WPF applications have anything like this in app.xaml.cs - remove all of that code.  It looks like in my app.xaml files, I have a StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" inside my Application declaration.  I let .Net figure out how and when to create it and open it.  I will edit my answer to show a working implementation.

Comment: @ElementalPete I need to check something before the windows start, so I make Application_Startup, and change StartupUri = "MainWindos.xaml" to "Startup = "Application_Startup"

Comment: Set a breakpoint and check, but Application_Startup will run when the application starts up whether you make that change or not...  Leave any check code that you need, and I suspect that you will see that it is hit even after you change the StartupUri back.  Your UI should be on the main thread; when you change the StartupUri to something other than a UI, you're probably screwing up that separation between the UI thread and your worker threads.

Comment: @ElementalPete Yes, you are right, even though I switch back to StartupUri, it still does not work.The breakpoint will go through Application_Startup,stop at MainWindow wnd = new MainWindow(); then go to my MainWindows() function and stop at constructor. I will try to start over a new one which is the only method I get

Comment: MainWindow wnd = new MainWindow() definitely should be removed.  If you set your StartupUri, then you don't need it.  If the idea is to check something before opening MainWindow(), then the place to do that is either in the MainWindow constructor, or in a "Load" event handler for MainWindow.

Comment: @SamXia adding to Petes fine comments, you really need to read the WPF documentation

Comment: @ElementalPete@MickyD Thanks you both, I use StartupUri and start over the new project, I think I lost something in system setting, but I do not know. @Clemens And also thank you